# Order of different Spring controller methods by params

Tags: spring-boot, controller

There are two methods in the following controller with different `params` values.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class ToyApiController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/toys", params = {"toySize=large"}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ToysVO listLargeToys(ListToyCommand listToyCommand) {
        // ...
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/toys", params = {"country"}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ToysVO listToysOfCountry(ListToyCommand listToyCommand) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The API below is expected to hit the `listLargeToys` method. The behavior is correct.

```
GET /api/v1/toys?toySize=large&max=10
```

The API below is expected to hit the `listToysOfCountry` method. However, the `listLargeToys` method is hit.

```
GET /api/v1/toys?country=france&toySize=large&max=10
```

The code in this post is simplified from actual code. I know that the two methods can be combined into a single method that checks the `toySize` and `country` parameters and returns different values accordingly. I'm just wondering whether the `listToysOfCountry` method can be hit by some tiny changes, e.g. specifying parameters like `params` without combining the two methods.

```
GET /api/v1/toys?country=france&toySize=large&max=10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a `!country` in `params` for `listLargeToys` API, `GET /api/v1/toys?country=france&toySize=large&max=10` no longer goes into `listLargeToys` API. Instead, it goes into `listToysOfCountry` as expected.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class ToyApiController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/toys", params = {"toySize=large", "!country"}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ToysVO listLargeToys(ListToyCommand listToyCommand) {
        // ...
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/toys", params = {"country"}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ToysVO listToysOfCountry(ListToyCommand listToyCommand) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need some like this:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value  = "/toys", 
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> toys(
        @RequestParam(value = "toySize", required = false) String  toySize,
        @RequestParam(value = "country", required = false) String country,
        @RequestParam(value = "max", required = false) Integer max) {
    
    if(null != max && max == 10) {
        System.out.println("You send 10 dude.");
    }
    
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("{ \"toySize\": "+ toySize +", \"country\": "+ country +", \"max\": "+ max +"}", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Using "required = false", you make param optional :)

Comment: I try not to split ListToyCommand into separate parameters since it's legacy code. So I tried the method above. It works. @Luno